# How to count number of events occured in same date and hour inside CSV file USING PHP

Tags: php, date, csv, count

i need to count the number of events occured in a same date and hour inside a CSV file.

I have an experimental project installed on a remote place of the city that measures temperature and umidity levels. It communicates (or should) with me every 5 minutes sending updated IP address to remote management (using a 3G connection).

I need to count the number of times it communicated with me to measure the 3G stability winthin specific climatic changes.

The log uses this format (separated by tabs):

```
Name            IP              DATE("d/m/Y G:i")
EXPERIMENTAL    187.118.104.121 13/08/2011 16:05
EXPERIMENTAL    187.118.104.121 13/08/2011 16:10
EXPERIMENTAL    187.118.104.121 13/08/2011 16:15
EXPERIMENTAL    187.118.104.121 14/08/2011 13:09
EXPERIMENTAL    187.118.104.121 14/08/2011 14:23
```

Example:

```
13/08 16H 3 Times
14/08 13H 1 Times
14/08 14H 1 Times
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read a csv file with the [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) function:

```
$count_by_date = array();

$fd = fopen('file.csv', 'r');
while ($fd && !feof($fd)) {
    $data = fgetcsv($fd, 0, "\t");

    list($date, $time) = explode(' ', $data[3]);

    if (!isset($count_by_date[$date])) {
        $count_by_date[$date] = 0;
    }
    $count_by_date[$date] ++;
}
```

Comment: Is there a threshold CSV size where it might be better to import to a database as Mark suggests in the comment to his own answer? (memory, cpu etc)

Comment: Just perfect ! Only had to change $date[3] to [2] to get the correct field. Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would be better suited for a command line script:

```
grep '13/08/2011' file.csv|wc -l
```

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the fast feedback. There will be multiple dates inside the file, i shoul've mentioned this. I need to sum the number of times the bot communicated per hour too (just edited), see above please.

Sorry for the lack of information !

Comment: Hours are easy to add: `grep '13/08/2011 16' file.csv|wc -l`

Comment: @lipe: as Paul said, hours are easy to add. If you need to do any finer slicing/dicing, you'd probably be better off sucking the CSV into a database and convert the textual timestamp into a DB-native date/time field, and do the heavy duty grouping/matching there. It'd be quicker do do the conversion ONCE. otherwise you'll be wasting a lot of cpu/disk time loading/parsing the csv file for every query you want to run.

Comment: Hi Marc, i agree about using a database to save time and hardware usage but im not very familiarized with any, after i get everything working i can start to fine-tune stuff and clear the code. Thank you very much for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I agree this would be better suited for a command line script but if that isn't an option you can use [substr_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php), passing the date.